# Is this sentence correct with "irreverent"?

Tags: word-usage

> You people were irreverent to POP's speech.

irreverent = *disrespectful - flippant - impious*

Is it a correct sentence according to syntax and semantics?

If it can be written in a better way, please post your example sentence.

Comment: I don't know, I don't think I would normally use *be irreverent to [thing]* like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is fine syntactically. However, *irreverent* is improper here unless POP is a deity, a religious dignitary, a sage, an eminent statesman, or some other person worth of *reverence*—which is, according to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reverence), "honor or respect felt or shown : deference; *especially* : profound adoring awed respect".

And ordinarily it is persons to whom *reverence* is due, not their actions, unless those actions are themselves imbued with deep symbolic significance.

*Disrespectful* is probably what you want: *respect* is a less exalted term, with a broader reference.

EDIT:
I should add that you will frequently see humorists, satirists, comedians and the like (or their works) referred to as *irreverent* where their targets are not figures worthy of reverence. In these cases, however, the word *irreverent* is used as a mark of approbation, because the artist is perceived as mocking those who have phoney pretensions to "reverence"—who take themselves more seriously than they deserve.

Comment: `You people were irreverent to POP` , is it correct?

Comment: It depends: who is POP?

Comment: POP is religious pundit.

Comment: @guru  Ah! in that case, *irreverent* **is** appropriate, and *You people were irreverent to POP* is correct. *You people were irreverent to POP's speech* would also be correct if POP's speech was something like a sermon, a formal discourse to his followers on a religious topic which listeners would be expected to listen to with reverence. But if POP was appearing on the Tonight Show, *reverence* would not be called for--just *respect*.

Comment: I think it still sounds weird even if POP is a figure worthy of reverence. As Cerberus said in his comment on the question, I almost never hear "irreverent to [somebody]", just "irreverent", almost always as a description of someone's attitude in general.

Comment: @alcas  The diminished sense you cite--basically what I describe in my EDIT--is now dominant, but in the proper context *irreverent* recovers its root significance (much like "awful" and awesome"). And *irreverent to*, though not frequent, is not unknown. So I think OP's sentence is a natural construction with which to scold people for a failure to exhibit the appropriate reverence.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely true - I would not say it's "wrong" in any sense - just pointing out that it is an uncommon use of the word.